# Trigger/Flow/Webservice Data Transfer Issue

Tags: apex, trigger, webservices, callout, visual-workflow

I am having a difficult time architecting the flow of declarative work to, and from, apex code.

What I want the flow to be is:

1. Apex Trigger
2. Flow (sends inputs to webservice)
3. Webservice Callout (Process.Plugin or InvocableMethod)
4. Flow (takes outputs from webservice)

My issues:

1. Because you can not call a webservice from a Trigger, I must make the callout a future method. Because the callout is a future method, you cannot use static variables to return the value from the future method to the synchronous code that called it. Aka I can not pass back output parameters into the flow.
2. Work Around 1: Create a process builder rather then the trigger to avoid future methods. Because of the order of DML and Callouts, I will always get an "Uncommitted Work Pending" error. The flow will make the DML and Callout loop thus causing DML to happen before and after the callout.
3. Work Around 2: perform a DML update on the record after making the callout and do not pass back any parameters to the flow. Because of the async/sync differences between the callout, there is a delay between when the future method makes the insert and when the next block of the flow is fired. I need the Object to be inserted before it can move on to the next block in the flow. Due to the nature of the flow, it loops through multiple times thus causing the same error `You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out`

Does anyone have any suggestions (other then platform events) to allow the data to be passed to and from a flow and webservice? I feel like there must be a way to make option #1 work.

Comment: You can make callout form future method and update the response the record itself.

Comment: @KiranMachhewar I do not believe I can because future methods can not have a return value.

Comment: That is true Olivia, it goes asynchronously. But you can update the result on the record itself. Tell this operation has to happen, is user using standard screen by which this request will be initiated or is there any custom screen. If custom screen is there then you can make real time synchronous  callout.

Comment: @KiranMachhewar there is actually no UI at all. The process is all fired in the background off of the trigger. The trigger is fired off of a field change or a input of an Opportunity.

Comment: If that is the case then do it in future. You will get the result in future method itself and then update the record itself. You don't need to depend on return value of future method. Inside future method when you get the result just update it on record. Consider future method as an async process where user is not waiting for response so you don't need to depend on direct real time result.

Comment: @KiranMachhewar I am doing that in Work Around 2. When I update the record itself I run into issues with the timing of the insert and the firing of the next flow block. I get an error `You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out`

Comment: You cannot make callout from DML context ( trigger, flows ) in real time. you need to use future method. That is the reason you are getting uncommitted work pending. Making callout from process with invocable action makes it real time in same transaction. In salesforce callouts are not allowed once the transaction touches the database. In your case it has already touched DB as you are doing callout in trigger. That is the reason the practice which is followed is future call is made from trigger.

Comment: @olivia - we had similar issue in one of our implementation , what best you can do is to make option 2 work in future and sync. Meaning , we know that we cannot call future from future method , so check if you are in future method , if so do operation synchronously else do it in future . I see that you want to do an DML -> WS -> DML which may contain data from the previous call out.

Comment: @freaker87 In regards to checking if we are in a Future method or not, doesn't it always register as being in a future method when you are actually in a future method? I am not sure where else I would check to see if I was in a future or not. See post updates.

Comment: @KiranMachhewar I have to use the Invocable method because I need to pass parameters into the webservice and then output the response back to the flow.

Answer (score 2):

Platform Events was the only way for me to accomplish this. I didn't want to have to go this route because I would have to restructure my flow but it ended up being the only solution.

I created a custom Platform Event in SF and updated my webservice code to instantiate the event, and set the field values to the returned callout values. I subscribed to the event in a wait element in the flow and pulled back in the values from the webservice into the flow. I had to put a counter on the event so I was able to track accordingly for when there are multiple events coming in at the same time.

With this solution I was able to go: Apex Trigger -> Pass Input Parameters to Flow -> Call Webservice -> Pass Output Parameters back to Flow.